# Schedule a power cycle / power reset on Netgear GS752TP POE switch ?

Tags: power-supply

Is it possible to schedule a power cycle / power reset for a POE device powered by a Netgear GS752TP ? Ive come across this sort of functionality before in PDUs but wondered if it can be done via a POE switch ?

I have a POE VOIP dect base that pretty much once a month freezes up and crashes. I have tried installing new firmwares etc as they come out, but it keeps happening, to combat this id like to power cycle the devices once every 3 weeks on Sunday at 3am.

Comment: Have you already tried telnet access after enabling the "**Remote Diagnostics**" option from the **Maintenance** tab of the web UI for managing the switch? If so you should be able to login with the admin credential, run `enable` then reboot, etc. such as https://roubert.name/joakim/gs110tp/ suggests for example but if you can get shell access to it, then you should be able to automate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a really simple workaround: Turning the port on and off using the a timed schedule should have the effect you desire (at least it did so according to recent case I had with one of my clients). Your model has that option as well, see [manual](http://www.downloads.netgear.com/files/GDC/GS728TP/GS752TP_GS728TP_GS728TPP_SWA_3Dec2013.pdf) page 47: "Timer Global Configuration".

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a Netgear switch and cannot experiment, but I discovered some interesting
information regarding switches in the same family as yours, although
not exactly for your model.

The article
[“Hidden” CLI interface on Netgear GS110TP](https://www.simweb.ch/blog/2014/02/hidden-cli-interface-on-netgear-gs110tp/)
describes finding that TCP port 60000 accepts CLI commands via telnet.
This port apparently exists in very many models of Netgear switches, both old and new.
The article lists several commands available in the help (`?` command), and warns:

> certain commands don’t seem to be recognized and may cause an instant reboot of the switch without saving to the NVRAM (i.e. #ip ssh server enable). That might be the cause why Netgear preferred disabling regular CLI access on this firmware since they didn’t want to support it. Still it can be quite useful to know that even on such a small entry-level manageable switch, there is still a  CLI available in case you need it.

If the information above does apply to your model, then the article
[How to reboot Netgear GS110TP with “hidden” telnet CLI](https://roubert.name/joakim/gs110tp/)
goes further by discovering the undocumented command `reload` which instantly
reboots the switch.
It also makes some recommendations for automating the running of a telnet session
to reboot the switch, which you may use or prefer to build your own.